# wordpress register_sidebar "class" does not work

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

It seems simple and straightforward - but its not.

I'm trying to register a class on the inner-part of the widget output. I'm using bootstrap 3, so I have to add a `panel-body` class to the inner part, whereas the entire widget itself is wrapped with a panel `panel-default` class.

Example:

```
register_sidebar( 
        array( 
                'name' => __( 'Home Page (Beside Content)' , 'symbiostock' ),
                'id' => 'home-page-beside-content',
                'class'         => 'panel-body',
                'before_widget' => '<div class="panel panel-default home-beside-content"><aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => '</aside></div>',
                'before_title' => '<div class="row panel-heading"><h3 class="featured-posts col-md-12">',
                'after_title' => '</h3></div>', ) );
```

One would think the "class=>'something" would register a class in the inner part of the widget. But it does not show up. Here is what happens:

```
<div class="panel panel-default home-beside-content">
   <aside class="widget widget_text" id="text-8">
      <div class="row panel-heading">
         <h3 class="featured-posts col-md-12">This is a test</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="textwidget">This is a test</div>
   </aside>
</div>
```

Whereas I am expecting:

```
<div class="panel panel-default home-beside-content">
   <aside class="widget widget_text" id="text-8">
      <div class="row panel-heading">
         <h3 class="featured-posts col-md-12">This is a test</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="textwidget panel-body">This is a test</div>
   </aside>
</div>
```

Notice the **"panel-body"** addition.

How can I fix this? The order of class nesting is important because I'm using bootstrap 3

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels

Comment: Please let me know if any of this question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with jQuery at the end of the footer.php file of my theme.

For each **panel**, you need get the childrens except **panel-heading**, and wrap all them in **panel-body**.

```
<script>
jQuery('.panel').each(function(index, value) {
 jQuery(value).children().not('.panel-heading').wrapAll('<div class="panel-body"></div>');
});
</script>
```

Note: I used the full word **JQuery** because shortcut **$** was not available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one would think that, but Wordpress often does exactly the opposite of what one would think!  :-)

I've had this problem before.  It doesn't work like that for some peculiar reason.  You'll need to wrap your widget in that class using some trickery.  Something like:

```
register_sidebar( 
    array( 
            'name' => __( 'Home Page (Beside Content)' , 'symbiostock' ),
            'id' => 'home-page-beside-content',
            'before_widget' => '<div class="panel panel-default home-beside-content"><aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</div></aside></div>',
            'before_title' => '<div class="row panel-heading"><h3 class="featured-posts col-md-12">',
            'after_title' => '</h3></div><div class="panel-body">', ) );
```

Note that you're starting the new div in 'after_title' and closing it in 'after_widget'.

Comment: I had come to that conclusion too - the problem is some widgets allow a user to not assign a title - in which case the HTML breaks! :D

Comment: why don't you add in some code to add in a space for a title if it doesn't exist?  that way you can make sure you always have a title.